# Android: call the assets folder from css

Tags: android, css, assets

I want to use a CSS in Android. I want to use the HelveticaNeue_Light font. this font is in the assets folder. I am not able to call it. How to do this?

```
body = "<HEAD><STYLE>.class1 {color:gray;text-align:left;font-family:\"HelveticaNeue_Light\";font-size:17px;}</STYLE></HEAD><BODY><div class=\"class1\"><P>"+ "TEXT" + "</P></BODY>";
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you have the font in your folder you could call it using the @font-face rule like so:

```
@font-face {
     font-family: HelveticaNeue_Light;
     src: url('/assets/HelveticaNeue_Light.otf');
}

.class1 {
     font-family:HelveticaNeue_Light, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

Ensure that the path to your font file is correct and change the extension of the font-file to be whatever extension it is.

Comment: how to integrate it in the body string above?

Comment: Can you not just add it as regular css rules the way you have your other rules added?

Comment: _body ="<HEAD><STYLE>.class1{color:gray;text-align:left;@font-face {font-family: HelveticaNeue_Light;src: url('file:///android_asset/HelveticaNeue_Light.ttf');};font-size:17px;}</STYLE></HEAD><BODY><div class=\"class1\"><P>"+TEXT ---- it didnt work!

Comment: You don't seem to have called the font to be displayed anywhere such as on the second bit of my example where I call it to be displayed on ".class1"